# Responsive font-size using css/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have created a page . which should be responsive across desktop, mobile and tablet.

whenever resizing page other than font looks responsive. but font-size remains same in mobile . it occupies major spaces and not user friendly too.

how to make it responsively?

my sample css :

```
body {
    font-size : 36px;
 }
```

here i am using `px` i heard `vw` will give responsive but i dont know how it works. which is the best font property for this?

or is there any bootstrap styles available for this?

Comment: use `css media queries` to define different `font-size` to `body` at different `screen break-points`. read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: i knew media query but there is even better solution for responsive .... i tried size property `vw` it works but not exactly ..... i mean font size should be scale based on screen size. for eg: if its site, total width : 100% means font size should for 40%, like wise in mobile device it should .. i need more clarification on `vw`

Answer (score 2):

try to use media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
   body {
     font-size : 25px;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
   body {
     font-size : 20px;
   }
}
```

Comment: i knew media query but there is even better solution for responsive .... i tried size property vw it works but not exactly ..... i mean font size should be scale based on screen size. for eg: if its site, total width : 100% means font size should for 40%, like wise in mobile device it should .. i need more clarification on vw –

Answer (score 2):

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

Answer (score 1):

Use a different unit of measure:

```
body {
  font-size : 2em;
}
```

Comment: Or set a new font size on each viewport.

Comment: will it scale automatically based on screen resolution? font size should be in specific ratio even resizing

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this yet but you should be able to use percentages, give your body your "base-font-size", and work with percentages from there.

```
html, body {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.some-element {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

Another option would be working with [REM](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/)